# postgresql table select or insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

hi everybody i have an issue in postgresql

i have a table like this

```
msisdn
31312312
123123123
123123123
12312312
123123
123123
```

and i have date table like

```
date
2018-05-01
2018-05-02
2018-05-03
2018-05-04
2018-05-05
```

so the problem is i'm new in postgresql and i want make another table like msisdn different but date still

```
  date           msisdn
2018-05-01      24312312
2018-05-01      124241241
2018-05-01      141241241
2018-05-01      124124124
2018-05-01      124214124
```

regards 
ps: sorry my bad english

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Please show us what you have done so far and what problem are you facing.

Comment: date is table or column name?

Comment: What's the relation between the two tables? What are the rules to populate msisdn in the new table?

Comment: select (select msisdn from msisdn_data), (select file_date from msisdn_date_tmp where date::date = ('2018-05-01')); but nothing happens suman.

Comment: thats the problem kaushik there is no relation

Comment: try with cross join

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Your sample results contain values not in the original tables.  Where do these come from?

Answer (score 0):

Their is no connection in date and msisdn as a separate table and when joined .

As rows values are different.

**edit**

something Like this may be your query

```
select "2018-05-01" as date ,msisdn from msisdn_data;
```